# Expression for moments in terms of lower moments

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

$$S_{n}\equiv\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{j}^{n}$$

If the values of $\{S_{1},S_{2},...,S_{N}\}$ are known, that places N constraints on the N unknowns $\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{N}\}$, so we could in theory calculate those values and use them to calculate all the higher $S_{n>N}$. However, that approach is impractical, and I don't need the $x_j$'s anyway.

Does there exist an expression for $S_{n}$ where $n>N$ in terms of $\{S_{1},S_{2},...,S_{N}\}$?

Examples:

If $N=1$, then $S_{n}=(S_{1})^{n}$ for all n.

If $N=2$ then $S_{3}=\frac{3}{2}S_{1}S_{2}-\frac{1}{2}S_{1}^{3}$ and $S_{4}=-\frac{1}{2}S_{1}^{4}+S_{2}S_{1}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}S_{2}^{2}$

Does a general expression in n and N exist, or do I need to write a program?

EDIT: This is related to [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), but I did not manage to derive a general expression from them.

Comment: I *assume* that such a relation can be derived from "Newton's identities": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities.

Comment: @MartinR  Probably so, but that was where I got stuck.  I'll add a mention of that to the Question.

Answer (score 1):

The [power sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^N x_j^n$ are related to the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
$$
e_{k} = \sum_{1\leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots <j_{k}\leq N}x_{j_{1}}\cdots x_{j_{k}}
$$
via [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities):
$$\tag{1}
ke_{k}=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{i-1}e_{k-i}S_{i} \right)+ (-1)^{k-1}S_k
$$
for $k = 1, \ldots, N$, and
$$ \tag{2}
0=\left(\sum _{i=k-N}^{k-1}(-1)^{i-1}e_{k-i}S_{i}\right) + (-1)^{k-1}S_k
$$
for $k \ge N+1$.

If $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ are given then $e_1, \ldots, e_N$ can be computed with $(1)$, and then all $(S_k)_{k > N}$ can be computed with $(2)$.

There is also the closed form expression
$$
e_{k}={\frac {(-1)^{k}}{k!}}B_{k}(-S_{1},-1!\,S_{2},-2!\,S_{3},\ldots ,-(k-1)!\,S_{k})
$$
where the $B_k$ are the [complete exponential Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials). I am not aware of an explicit (non-recursive) expression for $S_k$ with $k > N$ in terms of $S_1, \ldots, S_N$.